# barryvdh/laravel-cors not working for my routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cors, laravel-routing

I'm using [this laravel-cors package][1], I've read the docs and I've added the service provider to `config/app.php`.

After adding the middleware to `kernel.php` like so:

```
  protected $middleware = [
  \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,

];
```

It works for my passport routes, but not for my own routes.

**Passport routes**

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['api']
], function ($router) {
    Passport::routes();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
});
```

**My routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::resource('answers', 'AnswersController');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried just `['middleware' => ['api']]` in your `routes.php`?

Comment: No, but I don't see how that's a problem?

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately

Comment: What are you classing as "working"? On your passport routes?

Comment: As in, it doesn't add any headers

Answer (score 0):

I've read the entire code of the CORS middleware. It will only add headers, as per the RFC, when:

1. The request is a Pre-Flight request (OPTIONS)
2. The request has an `Origin` header other than the one your API resides on.
3. The remote host that is trying to join your API is allowed as per the CORS config.

Make sure you publish the CORS config and edit it to your needs.

[See the source](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/blob/63d89f8dda9280c68d36f891266418b2ebcb66b6/src/Stack/CorsService.php#L60)