# CORS middlware running on preflight OPTIONS request but not on main request

Tags: php, laravel, api, http-headers, middleware

I've created a middleware that handles my CORS requests:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $headers = [
           'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
           'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
       ];

     $response = $next($request);
     foreach ($headers as $key => $value){
       $response->headers->set($key, $value);
      }
     return $response;
    }
}
```

And I've added it to my `kernel.php`:

```
'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        'cors'
    ],
```

When I make a `GET` request to `/user` everything works fine, but when I make a `POST` request to `/api/answers` I get a CORS error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/answers. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`. Both are in my `api.php`:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        $user = $request->user();
        $user->load('locations.company');
        $user->load([
            'questionlists' => function ($query) {
                $query->with('questions.type');
                $query->with('difficulty');
            }
        ]);

        $amountOfCompletes = count($user->completes);
        $user->amountOfCompletes = $amountOfCompletes;
        return $user;
    });

    Route::resource('answers', 'AnswersController');
});
```

Comment: my suggestion use this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors. Save you some time for this.

Comment: I tried, gave me a different issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978486/barryvdh-laravel-cors-not-working-for-my-routes?noredirect=1#comment69172987_40978486

Answer (score 0):

use class reference if you haven't defined your middleware as your route middleware

```
'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
    ],
```

Comment: My apologies, I have: `'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,` I tried adding it to the post but my cursor keeps jumping in SO's editor

Comment: can you check by adding dd to your middleware and confirm if middleware is called or its bypassed? also i would suggest using laravel-cors package
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: That package doesn't work for me unfortunately, dd doesn't do anything

Comment: ok can you confirm if the middleware handle method is called by using dd in your handle method?

Comment: When I `echo` something it shows in my preview tab for the options request but not for the other. `dd` doesn't show up in either

Comment: No, I'm using my frontend app

Comment: Postman doesn't work with my auth as I'm using a password client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129889/discussion-between-sam-and-g3mini).